# Install FreeBSD kernel

Tags: freebsd, kernel

I'm trying to setup Asterisk, and one of the pre-installation tasks is setting up zaptel.  I get the message that I need to install the FreeBSD kernel source code to /usr/src.  When I run `make buildworld` I get the message `make: don't know how to make buildworld. Stop`

I'm a bit new to FreeBSD so I have no clue on how to proceed.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't have any files to build. Start with [obtaining the kernel source codes](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/cvsup.html).
Then use link petre provided or [use this one](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/updating-upgrading.html)

Answer (score 1):

starting frome [here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/kernelconfig.html) would be a good idea